# Need Help Setting Future Date in MySQL via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date, strtotime

I am trying to insert a future date into a MySQL table from PHP.  I have been able to insert the current date using `strtotime` but when I add time to this call it does not seem to insert it.  Here is the code:

```
<?php
$currentDate = strtotime('now');
$expirationDate = strtotime('+ 90 days');

include_once "mysql-connect.php";       

$cur = "UPDATE table SET current_date = FROM_UNIXTIME($currentDate) WHERE ...";

if (!mysql_query($cur,$con))
{
die('Heres Your Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "the date is set";

$exp = "UPDATE table SET expiration_date = FROM_UNIXTIME($expirationDate) 
WHERE ...";


if (!mysql_query($exp,$con))
{
die('Heres Your Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo " expiration date is set";

mysql_close($con)
?>
```

Like I said, when I run this it will insert the current date into the current_date row as requested.  For some reason it will not insert expiration_date which is 90 days in front of the current date.  I have verified that the expiration date is being picked up as 90 days in the future.  Why is this not working?

Comment: Is the last update returning any errors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it in MySQL [directly](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add):

```
$days = 90;

$sql = "UPDATE ... SET expiration_date = DATE_ADD(current_date, INTERVAL $days DAY);"
```

which'll save you the excess round-tripping from datetime->unix timestamp->datetime.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad idea to use strtotime() function because it does not always work nicely.

Rather than doing dates in PHP, I'd suggest you do them directly in MySQL that provides a decent pool of date-time functions - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html.

For your query, you can do:

```
UPDATE `table` 
SET `current_date` = NOW(), `expiration_date` = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 90 DAY) 
WHERE ...;
```

By the way, for your query case, does the second UPDATE return any errors. Which part of the following IF executes?